# Parse .phtml file in Java

Tags: java, jsoup, php

I'm trying to parse a phtml file from a project and save modifications to this file with Java. I actually use Jsoup API to parse this file. My problem is the saving step. Lets see an example :

**PHTML FILE :**

```
<div id="header"> 
<div id="logo"> 
    <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo_pic" /> 
</div>
<div id="welcome">
    <span id="welcome_title">
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

**Java parsing :**

```
File testFile = new File("C:\\Users\\root\\Desktop\\test.phtml");
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(testFile, "UTF-8");
        Element essai = doc.getElementById("welcome_title");
        essai.appendText("Application NAME!");
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(testFile, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(doc.html());
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Result i want to have should be like this :**

```
<div id="header"> 
<div id="logo"> 
    <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo_pic" /> 
</div>
<div id="welcome">
    <span id="welcome_title">
    Application NAME!
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```

**Result i have for the moment :**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div id="header"> 
            <div id="logo"> 
                <img src="images/logo.png" id="logo_pic" /> 
            </div> 
            <div id="welcome"> 
                <span id="welcome_title"> Application NAME!</span> 
            </div> 
        </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that i must keep a phtml format with only div elements for my application. How can i reach the good result? Any idea? Thx for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
writer.write(essai.outerHtml());
```

instead of

```
writer.write(doc.html());
```

Comment: Thx for help .outerHtml() was what i needed.